# CollectionViewCell Alignment XCode 7.2

Tags: xcode7.2

As you can see in the screenshot below, when I add the collectionview to this view controller, the cell appears in the lower left, or actually if I expand the collectionview it's center left basically. Why? Normally it appears in the top left by default when I open a new project. I'm having trouble getting it to appear as it should. Is this related to not using auto-sizing, or is this some other setting I am missing?

[image]

My settings:

[image]

and:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution but rather an answer as to why this happens. Through experimentation it turns out that this happens only when a view controller is embedded within a navigation controller. This appears to be a bug with no fix so far.